# Titileize method to capitalize large words in titles

Tags: ruby

I am working on a method to capitalize the first letter of each word of a sentence passed in unless its one of the little words. (This first word in a sentence will always be capitalized no matter what)

I have the following:

```
def titleize(t)
little = ["over", "the", "and"]
q = t.split(" ")
u = []

    q.each do |i|
        p = i.split("")
        p[0] = p[0].upcase
        r = p.join("")
            if i == q[0]
                u.push(r)
            elsif i == little[0] || i == little[1] || i == little[2]
                u.push(i)
            else
                u.push(r)
            end
        end
    s = u.join(" ")
    return s

end
```

When I run i through the test I get:

```
     Failure/Error: titleize("the bridge over the river kwai").should == "The Br
     idge over the River Kwai"
       expected: "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
       got: "The Bridge over The River Kwai" (using ==)
```

Why is the 2nd "the" in the sentence getting capitalized?

Comment: Side note, consider using descriptive variable names like `sentence,`, `words`, `characters` rather than `t`, `q`, `p`. Does a lot for readability.

Comment: You've selected @sawa's answer, but not upvoted it.  You are under no obligation to upvote any answer, but I mention this as you a new member and may not realize you can upvote the answer you select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `q[0]` is `"the"`, so when `i` is `"the"`, it satisfies the condition:

```
i == q[0]
```

A better way to do it is:

```
Little = %w[over the and]
def titleize s
  s.gsub(/\w+/)
  .with_index{|w, i| i.zero? || Little.include?(w).! ? w.capitalize : w}
end

titleize("the bridge over the river kwai")
# => "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
```

Comment: Because you have `u.push(r)` under that condition.

Comment: I'm talking about the second The not the first one

Comment: I understand now, hmmm so how can I solve this, I need to capitalize the first word no matter what not sure how then.

Comment: That is a different question. Did my answer answer your question or not?

Comment: Okay, I gave a way to do it.

Comment: That solution was too advanced for me but I found another way! THanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Here's another solution from my original suggestion, with code:

```
class String
  def titleize(exclusions)
    words = self.split.map do |word|
      exclusions.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
    end
    words.first.capitalize!
    words.join(" ")
  end
end

string = "the bridge over the river kwai"
exclusions = %w{ over the and }
p string.titleize(exclusions)
  #=> "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
```

Original answer:
How about just capitalizing each word in the entire string, then using gsub to substitute the words with their lowercased versions when appropriate?

```
string = "the bridge over the river kwai"
exclusions = %w{ over the and }
p string.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ").gsub(/(?<!^)(#{exclusions.join("|")})/i) {|word| word.downcase}
  #=> "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
```

Comment: It does not answer the question.

Comment: Note `self.split(" ")` can be shortened to `split`.  Also, I don't think `str` is not a good choice for the name of an array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @CarySwoveland. I always forget about using split without any args.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: You don't need `self` either, as it is the default receiver.  I know some people like to include `self` for stylistic reasons, but I'm in the camp that believes one should never include unnecessary elements, lest the reader assume it's needed for some reason.  There are of course a few situations where `self` is needed, such as `self.class`, `self.an_accessor` and `self[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the above:

```
def titleize(s)
  s.sub( /\w+/) { |w| w.capitalize }
   .gsub(/\w+/) { |w| Little.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize }
end
```

Try it:

```
s =<<THE_END
to protect his new shoes from the rain, a man stood atop a stack of
newspapers in Times Square.  When the newsstand's proprietor asked
if he realized what he was standing on, he replied, "of course,
these are the times that dry men's soles".
THE_END

Little = ["the", "and", "a", "on", "to", "from", "in"]

titleize(s)
  #=> "To Protect His New Shoes from the Rain, a Man Stood Atop a Stack Of \n
  #    Newspapers in Times Square.  When the Newsstand'S Proprietor Asked\n
  #    If He Realized What He Was Standing on, He Replied, \"Of Course,\n
  #    These\nAre the Times That Dry Men'S Soles\".\n"
```